# Can I change the query params value on Rxjs Retry?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have this service with return null initially (init background job) `[ this.q = true]`. But later if I change it change to `[ this.q = false]` and if the job successes it will return value.

So, 1st I need to call `[ this.q = true]` and retry `[ this.q = false]`.
But the below code didn't works. it always make https://api.example.com?q=true

```
return this.http.get('https://api.example.com?q=' + this.q)
  .map((res: any) => {    
    if (res === null) {          
      throw new Error("not enough tiles !");
    }                
    return res;
  }).catch((e) => {    
    this.q = false;
    return error;
  })
  .retryWhen(e => e.delay(2000))
  .retry(3);
```

Comment: you have this.q=false in "catch", not in the if(res===null){this.q=true;...}. a response null can be valid

Comment: response null is valid that's why I throw the error when `res === null` which send the control into catch. I put console and it got executed.

Comment: 1st request `https://api.example.com?q=true` and it will return null. After that, I have to retry with `https://api.example.com?q=false`.

Comment: I think that throw new Error("..") not make the programs goes to "catch", but I'm not sure

Answer (score 7):

`Retry` re-subscribes to the source Observable, so, if you want to change the parameter of the `get` request on `retry`, you should make the calculation of the parameter value part of your source observable. E.g.

```
return Observable.of('https://api.example.com?q=')
  .concatMap((baseUrl) => this.http.get(baseUrl + this.q))
  .map((res: any) => {    
    if (res === null) {          
      throw new Error("not enough tiles !");
    }                
    return res;
  }).catch((e) => {    
    this.q = false;
    return error;
  })
  .retryWhen(e => e.delay(2000))
  .retry(3);
```

Comment: Or even just `Observable.defer(() => this.http.get('https://api.example.com?q=${this.q}')),map(...).catch(...).retryWhen(...).retry(3)` instead of `of().concatMap`

Answer (score 2):

Upvotes @zafeiris.m, for inspiring me this solution.

Not exactly an answer to current post :
I needed to call a service returning an observable of tickets list, when http answer received then call again the service with increased page offset, repeat until no next page link exist.

```js
searchTickets() {
    const onSearchResult = (listTicketsResponse: ListTicketsResponse) => {
      this.searchOffset += this.searchPageSize;
      this.allSearchedTickets.push(...listTicketsResponse.result.elements);
    }

    of (1) // Create an observable 
    .pipe( // pipe it just to concatened it with http service call 
      concatMap(() => { // concatened it with the http search tickets service, to ensure params are updated when repeatWhen be call
        return this.ticketsService.searchTickets(searchTicketsRequest, this.searchOffset, this.searchPageSize); // return observable of request to API 
      }), // repeat when previous observable complete 
      repeatWhen((obs: Observable < ListTicketsResponse > ) => {
        return obs.pipe(
          delay(100)); // wait a little  
      }),
      retryWhen((obs: Observable < ListTicketsResponse > ) => {
        console.error("ERROR WITH searchTickets WAIT 10 secondes ")
        return obs.pipe(
          delay(10000)
        );
      }), // take while API response tell us next link exist
      takeWhile((listTicketsResponse: ListTicketsResponse) => {
        onSearchResult(listTicketsResponse); // add to list, update offset
        return (listTicketsResponse.result.links.next ? .href ? .length ? ? 0) > 0; // true if next url is not empty
      }),
    ).subscribe();
}
```